# How to get all variables an put it on FPU stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, fpu, x87

I have the following code (this is the code written by my lecturer) which calculates the root of the number (a).

```
    [bits 32]

    call getaddr ; get the runtime addres of format

    format db "delta = %lf", 0xA, 0
    offset equ $ - format
    a      dq 6.0 ;
    b      dq 10.0
    c      dq 16.0

    getaddr:

        finit

        mov eax, [esp]
        lea eax,[eax+offset]

        fld qword[eax]
        fsqrt

        lea eax, [esp+4]
        fstp qword[eax]

        call[ebx+3*4]; start screen print instuctions 
        add esp, 3*4

        push 0
        call[ebx+0*4]
```

Now, I need to modify this code to perform several operations on the three numbers given, and here is my problem because I have no idea how to put them on the FPU stack. Can anyone tell me what should I do? I tried to do the same as above, but refer to the next elements of the stack (below my attempt) but unfortunately it does not work properly (the program does not display anything). I will be very grateful for any help. A few days ago I added a similar question, I got some advice on how to improve the code so that it is more readable and better at all, but my lecturer does not accept solutions other than what he presented.
My attempt to get b variable instead of a:

```
    mov eax, [esp+4]
    lea eax,[eax+offset]

    fld qword[eax]
    fsqrt

    lea eax, [esp+4]
    fstp qword[eax]

    call[ebx+3*4]; start screen print instructions
    add esp, 3*4

    push 0
    call[ebx+0*4]
```

Comment: FYI, `mov eax, [esp]` loads (what would normally be) the return address and is a weird shellcode-style hack.  You don't normally want to mix data and code like that.  Normally the caller would pass a pointer in a register or on the stack separate from the return address.

Comment: Why did you make a new question instead of responding to [your old one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61854668/417501)?

Comment: @fuz Because in that question I described my problem too chaotically, I saw that the code was really bad, as you and others said and I got tangled up myself. An additional problem was that I had to stick to the pattern we got from the lecturer

Comment: @nath425 Sounds good!  But a few more comments would help make this easier to understand.  For example, I don't understand why you do `lea eax, [esp+4]; fstp qword [eax]` instead of simply `fstp qword [esp+4]`.  I thought that perhaps you need to have `eax` set to this value for later, but without comments it is entirely unclear.  I also don't understand where the arguments to the print routine are placed which is crucial to understanding what went wrong.  Again: no comments, so I can only guess.

Comment: @fuz Unfortunately, we are taught in such a strange way, as I wrote earlier, the lecturer does not accept any other way than the one he showed us (i.e. exactly the one I inserted). Thank you for wanting to help me, below I have already received an answer that solved this problem (although another one appeared, but of a different nature). So, I think we can leave it already because I know that a lot could be done differently and better in this example, but why I didn't do it I have already described it, it is not up to me; P

Comment: @nath425  Sounds good!  I wish you all the best with your assignment.  I hope your eccentric lecturer is not going to diminish your love for programming.

Comment: @fuz 
Thank you so much. To be honest it is very annoying and discouraging but I won't give up easily!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you put the `+4` to access the next variable (i.e. `b`) into the wrong place.  You start off with `mov eax, [esp+4]` instead of `mov eax, [esp]`.  However, you should rather change `lea eax, [eax+offset]` to `lea, eax, [eax+offset+8]` instead.

Note that you need `+8`, because the `qword` values are 64-bit and thus take 8 bytes each.

And here is the reason why:

The very first instruction is a `call getattr`, which is really just a dirty trick to do `push ADRESS_OF_FORMAT`.  So, on the stack (at position `[esp]`) you have the address of the data structure at the very beginning of the code.  However, as far as the code is concerned, there is nothing there at `[esp+4]`—there is really just this one address on the stack.

With `mov eax, [esp]` you then load this address into `eax`.  So, `eax` is now a pointer to the string `"delta = ..."`.  By adding `offset` to it (`lea eax, [eax+offset]` is a fancy way for `add eax, offset`), you get the address of the variable `a`.  It is here that you now need to add 8 more to get the address of `b`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it finally works and above all I understand where the error was and why it is good now. I appreciate you :)